# Figlet/TOIlet fonts can't be loaded in the terminal

Tags: gnome-terminal, fonts, ascii-art

I was trying to use TOIlet, and it worked just fine in the beginning. Later I was trying to install some program to record my terminal, such as asciinema, and I encountered this error every time I try to run TOIlet.

```
error: could not load font ascii9
```

I tried all other kinds of fonts and the only one that works is the term.

I would appreciate any help, thanks!

Comment: I too would like to know the answer to this, where have all the figlet fonts gone. Like everything in linux, it's gone down the toilet.

Comment: even me, would like to know the solution

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you missing the `toilet-fonts` package.

```
sudo apt install toilet-fonts
```

The fonts are there:

```
$ dpkg -L toilet-fonts | grep tlf
/usr/share/figlet/ascii12.tlf
/usr/share/figlet/ascii9.tlf
/usr/share/figlet/bigascii12.tlf
/usr/share/figlet/bigascii9.tlf
/usr/share/figlet/bigmono12.tlf
/usr/share/figlet/bigmono9.tlf
/usr/share/figlet/circle.tlf
/usr/share/figlet/emboss.tlf
/usr/share/figlet/emboss2.tlf
/usr/share/figlet/future.tlf
/usr/share/figlet/letter.tlf
/usr/share/figlet/mono12.tlf
/usr/share/figlet/mono9.tlf
/usr/share/figlet/pagga.tlf
/usr/share/figlet/smascii12.tlf
/usr/share/figlet/smascii9.tlf
/usr/share/figlet/smblock.tlf
/usr/share/figlet/smbraille.tlf
/usr/share/figlet/smmono12.tlf
/usr/share/figlet/smmono9.tlf
/usr/share/figlet/wideterm.tlf
```

Another issue can be if somehow `toilet` was using another directory for fonts, force the right directory with the `--directory` (or `-d`) option:

```
$ toilet --directory /usr/share/figlet/ -f ascii9 Ubuntu 
                                          
 m    m #                      m          
 #    # #mmm   m   m  m mm   mm#mm  m   m 
 #    # #" "#  #   #  #"  #    #    #   # 
 #    # #   #  #   #  #   #    #    #   # 
 "mmmm" ##m#"  "mm"#  #   #    "mm  "mm"#
```